# Fusionauth localization support

Tags: fusionauth

We are developing an application that needs to have custom look per tenant.

[The Themes API coming on 1.8.0](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/themes#create-a-theme) informs that in that "Themes are configured per Tenant".

We would also need to support several languages per tenant.

Will the new themes feature allow for localization?

Are there plans for supporting email templates per tenant?

Answer (score 1):

The 1.8.0 version update will be moving most of the System Configuration to the Tenant. This will include:

- Email templates
- Password policy
- Theme configuration
- OAuth configuration
- JWT configuration
- Event configuration

The 1.8.0 release will not include localization support for themes, but this is on the roadmap. I can't say for sure when it will be available.

Feel free to contact us through the website to discuss expediting that feature for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info!